# What do the square brackets after ES6 function do?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, object-literal

Recently I was looking for a way to rewrite an ugly switch/case statement and came across [this Medium article](https://medium.com/chrisburgin/rewriting-javascript-replacing-the-switch-statement-cfff707cf045).

I rewrote my switch/case into an es6 function like this:

```
const url = category => ({
          'itemA': itemAService.getItemCategories(payload),
          'itemB': itemBService.getItemCategories(payload),
        })[category]
```

When I call this function with something like `const response = url(category);` it works, which is great! But then I got to wondering what exactly the `[category]` means at the end of the function. I thought maybe it was an Immediately Invoked Function, but that didn't seem right either.

The article mentions that it's an object literal, but when I went to the MDN docs I couldn't find anything that explained what this is or what it does, or even any examples that showcase this same thing.

So what does it do?

Comment: Same as `object[property]`. More here: [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation).

Comment: It's just a key accessor. The function returns an Object, so essentially it's just assigning an object, and then using bracket notation to pick the object passed in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not "after" the function, it is *in* the functions body. It could also be written as:

```
  const url  = category => {
    const obj = {
      'itemA': itemAService.getItemCategories(payload),
      'itemB': itemBService.getItemCategories(payload),
    };

    return obj[category];
 };
```

So this is basically just a dynamic property lookup in the object.

Comment: Ah ok that makes sense. I guess I was just thrown off by the square brackets because I'm so used to seeing IIFE functions. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: JavaScript's shorthand notations are certainly ripe for creating confusing syntax. You have to look carefully to tell this isn't some kind of IIFE.

Comment: @Barmar: Looking at the AST can help, if one is comfortable with that. Shameless plug: https://astexplorer.net/ .

Answer (score 4):

That shorthand is roughly equivalent to the following traditional function syntax:

```
function url(category) {
    var obj = {
      'itemA': itemAService.getItemCategories(payload),
      'itemB': itemBService.getItemCategories(payload),
    };
    return obj[category];
}
```

It's easier to see what's happening when you create a named variable for the object.

The parentheses are needed around the object in the arrow function because if an arrow function begins with `{` it's treated as a body containing statements, rather than a value to return.

They could have put `[category]` immediately after the object literal, rather than after the close parenthesis, that might have been clearer.

Answer (score 1):

What confuses you here are the braces.

Imagine that you have an object expression and you use a property assessor on the variable which points to the object.

```
obj = {foo: 1, bar: 2}
return obj["foo"];    //returns 1
```

Now, how would you call a property assessor on an object literal? You need braces around them to complete the shorthand syntax.

```
return {foo: 1, bar: 2}["foo"];    // WRONG Syntax
return ({foo: 1, bar: 2})["foo"];  // CORRECT syntax
```

So, your function can be rewritten using the following traditional syntax.

```
function getUrl(category) {

   return ({
          'itemA': itemAService.getItemCategories(payload),
          'itemB': itemBService.getItemCategories(payload),
        })[category]

}
```